# Get Data files from Python Package to local working directory

Tags: python-3.x, package, python-packaging

I am making a package that uses flask. I will be using a single command to create the project.  For the flask application to run properly, I want the following directories in the user's local directory-

```
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   └── style.css
├── templates
│   └── index.html
```

How do I package the code so that I am able to store these files in the user's local directory?

Comment: I am trying to create something similar to what django has. The command django-admin startproject mysite craetes the project in user's local directory.

Comment: it's usually very ill-adviced to drop files under a user's home directory, unless you are writing a templating project. If that's what you're trying to do, you should look into [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/README.html). If you want to allow your users to have control over their configs, you should let [appdirs](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/) pick the right directory to put the config files for you, and leave the flask code within the package that the users install. Or did I misread your intentions here?